# rails: authlogic passing a session parameter to UserSession.find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, authlogic

I'm passing the user session via a parameter (params['session_key']) for one controller (it's a flash upload script so I have to pass it via a param).

I don't know how to access the user session with authlogic by using the raw param string.

Normally I do this:

```
@current_user_session = UserSession.find
```

I thought I could do this:

```
@current_user_session = UserSession.find(session_key)
```

But passing the key as a parameter to the method doesn't appear to work.

Any idea how I look up the user session with authlogic when I can't access the session cookie and need to use a param with the session key?

Comment: Are you sure this is what you should be doing? Accessing the session without the cookie does seem to fit any normal usage pattern. Maybe you actually want the user model. `Authlogic` provides a number of options such as `single_access_token` or the `perishable_token` which you could use as your lookup key for the upload

Comment: Yeah, that might work. Thanks! I'll take a look and see.

Answer (score 1):

In order to flash to get authenticated you need a "hack" that is quite tricky to get working.

don't know if you're using uploadify but you might need the same solution indicated here:
http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/12/22/flash-uploaders-rails-cookie-based-sessions-and-csrf-rack-middleware-to-the-rescue

the only problem is, I never found a 100% working solution on the internet, I started with this post and solved the problem manually with quite a pain here at work.

As I recall, I added exception on protect_from_forgery to my tmp_uploader method

Another necessary thing was on the render for the method where I had to specifically indicate:

```
render :action => 'tmp_uploader.js.rjs'
```

There is also a problem with filters using respond_to method that my AppController used, also added the tmp_uploader method to his :except list

Sorry I can't recall exactly what else I had to do, but it really was a big pain.

Comment: Yes, I'm using uploadify. Yeah, I looked at that post before. I do have middleware running but it's not working for some reason. Maybe you should do a post on your solution ;-). I think I'm close though, so I'll post what works for me.

Comment: dunno if you saw but I edited my answer with what I recalled doing.